# Retrieving multiple cell value from google sheets in html

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am totally new in coding.
I have a code which can retrieve cell value based on the specific range of google published sheet. specific cell value is coming from the google sheet url. Because I added `&range=A1` specifically in the URL. The rage can be extended by changing the url into `&range=A1:F20` as an example.

my code is working fine. The problem is, it only parses one cell value.

## What I want:

I want to parse more specific cell values (e.g. A1, A3, C5, F9 etc) at the same time without requesting google sheet link for too many times.

By using the following below code I can retrieve and display only one cell value.

```
<body onload='loadData()'>
<div id="display"></div>
```

But I want to retrieve more individual cell values. (e.g. A1, A3, C5, F9 etc)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<body onload='loadData()'>
<div id="display"></div>


<script>

function loadData() {
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you help please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You would probably be better off using [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) and their [library for the web](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md).

Answer (score 0):

```js
      var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1:F20&output=csv";
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
          const result = xmlhttp.responseText;
          const values = result.split('\n').map(row => row.split(','));
          console.log(values[0][0]); // A1
          console.log(values[2][0]); // A3
          console.log(values[4][2]); // C5
          console.log(values[8][5]); // F9
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Hi, when I use your code it displaying nothing. Can you please provide the full code?

Comment: It is only logging. No one know in what format you want to insert to the html.

Comment: I want to display google sheet cell values as  text/number in html individually in various places. For example, inside <td></td> tag. please help. Please add full code. So that I can use your code and display individual cell values in various places (where required).

Comment: For example, I want to display cell value inside of table.  <td>cell value of A1</td> <td>cell value of A3</td><td>cell value of A5</td> etc

Comment: I'm waiting for your response. Please reply. If you have any query please ask me.  Hope you will help. Thank you